# how to use concentration inequality to prove a function is positive, given its mean is positive?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given a function $f(w,x)$ where $x$ is independent variable and $w$ is random variable. How to prove it is positive given

(1) its expectation is positive, i.e. $P(Ef>0)=1$

(2) it concentrates to its mean, i.e. $P(|f-Ef|\geq t)\leq 2\exp{(-t^2)}$.

I tried the following two ways:
Let $\alpha>0$,

then
(1)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(f>0)>P(f>\alpha)&=P(f-Ef+Ef>\alpha)\\
&>P(f-Ef>\alpha \text{ and }Ef>0)\\
&\geq P(f-Ef>\alpha)+P(Ef>0)-1\\
&=P(f-Ef>\alpha)+1-1\\
&\geq \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

(2)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(f<0)&=P(f-Ef+Ef<0)\\
&<P(f-Ef<0\text{ or }Ef<0)\\
&\leq P(f-Ef<0)+P(Ef<0)\\
&=P(f-Ef<0)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Then I don't know how to proceed.

**Update:**

**I came up with the following, and could you help to check whether this is correct?**

First, assume we know hat $f$ concentrates to its mean in the way that $$P(f-Ef\leq -t)\leq \exp(-t^2)$$ where $t>0$ (left tail probability).

Equivalently $$P(f\leq Ef-t)\leq \exp(-t^2)$$

Consider $t>Ef$, take $-a:=Ef-t<0$, then

$$P(f\leq -a)\leq \exp(-(Ef+a)^2)$$

where $a$ actually represents the deviation of $f\leq -a$ from being $f>0$.

From this inequality we can see that when $a$ increases (i.e. deviation increases), the upper bound $\exp(-(Ef+a)^2)$ decreases.

**Thus, we can say: $f>0$ with high probability, since the more we deviation from what we expected (i.e. $f>0$), the smaller the probability is.**

Comment: By moving from $Ef-t$  to $a:=t-Ef$ you are conflating a parameter of the bound (e.g., $C$) with a property of the random variable you are bounding. We cannot tell if $a  \to \infty$ implies $ t \to \infty$ or $Ef \to -\infty$, but either way what you've shown is that random variables are more likely to be closer (in a suitable sense) to their mean than further away from it.

Comment: @User5678 I am not sure if I understood correctly. $a\rightarrow\infty$ implies $t\rightarrow\infty$ if we assume $Ef>0$ is bounded. and why this is important? I am not sure whether I got the point..

Comment: I.e., $\lim_{a\to\infty} P(f \leq -a) \to 0$ doesn't seem helpful here

Comment: @User5678 If consider $a$ goes to infinity, then $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}P(f\leq -a)$ means the probability that the deviation goes to infinity. This is upper bounded by $\lim \exp(-(Ef+a)^2)$ which is $0$. This makes sense right? What I would need is to show the larger the deviation, the smaller the probability. Now taking the deviation as infinity, the probability is zero, which seems does not contradict anything for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: $\lim_{a \to -\infty}P(f\leq-a) = 0$ Just means that $f$ is increasingly unlikely to be negative but not that it's positive with high probability

Comment: @User5678 'with high probability' I meant that: the larger deviation we are from our expected event ($X>0$), the smaller the probability is. Is this consistent of your definition of 'whp'? Thanks

Comment: whp has a technical definition that I was assuming you meant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_high_probability

Comment: Bottom line is that you need more constraints on your random variable to prove it is strictly positive or even that it is positive with high probability ... there are some very strange distributions out there (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are asking if a random variable $X$ is [sub-guassian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Gaussian_distribution) with positive mean does that imply it is positive $a.s.$.

A counterexample is any Gaussian distribution with positive mean.

$$P\left(|X-EX| \geq t \right) \leq 2\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{C^2}\right)$$ for some $C>0$

Comment: maybe being 'almost surely' is too much. Can we say $X$ is positive 'with high probability'?

Comment: @chloe Unfortunately no -- we can't say it becomes strictly positive "whp" in the technical sense because our tuning parameter $C$ gets zeroed out by setting $t=0$, leaving us with a trivial upper bound of $2$. If we allow $t>0$ we still don't know which side of the expected value most of that probability is falling, since we are relying on absolute value.

I think if you make an assumption like $f$ is symmetric about the mean then you can say that half that probability is below the mean, and hence if the mean is far from zero very little will be below zero.

Comment: I added an update, and it seems work. Could you also check it? Thank you very much!

Comment: @chloe a good example is a normal distribution with positive mean -- in that case the random variable becomes positive with high probability, but not sure if that is just a special case.

Comment: Although $P(|f-Ef|\leq t)=P(f-Ef\geq t \text{and} f-Ef\leq t)$, I was not able to find how to get the left-side tail from two-sided tail bound. Instead, I assume that the left tail bound $P(f-Ef<-t)\leq\exp(-t^2)$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @chloe that seems to imply that there is equal probability of a positive or negative deviation of at least size $|t|$

Comment: I think they are different, not sure it is correct: Let's take $a=0.1$. Then $P(f\leq -0.1)\leq \exp(-(Ef+0.1)^2)$ and $P(f\leq 0.1)\leq\exp(-(Ef-0.1)^2)$.

Comment: @chloe I was referring to the move from $2\exp(-t^2)$ to $\exp(-t^2)$ on the RHS in $P(f-Ef\leq -t)\leq \exp(-t^2)$

Answer (score 0):

The usage of $w$ and $x$ seems irrelevant. Your question seems to be to find a bound on $P[F\leq 0]$ given $F$ is a random variable with mean $m>0$ that satisfies $P[|F-m|\geq t] \leq e^{-t^2}$ for all $t>0$.

Note that $$P[F\leq 0] = P[F-m\leq -m]\leq P[|F-m|\geq m]$$

---

Also note that you will not be able to prove $F$ is almost surely positive, you can only provide a bound.

Comment: thanks for taking time to write up! And the upper bound of $P(F\leq 0)$ is $\exp(-m^2)$, which depends on $m$. Since $m>0$ we have the upper bound of $P(F\leq 0)\leq 1$. This seems that this bound is not meaningful...

Comment: My intuition is that: we know $EF>0$ and we know $F$ concentrates on $EF$, then it should tell us $F>0$ with high probability as well?

Comment: Yes, and so the likelihood of going negative is smaller when $m$ is very far above 0, which is exactly what the $e^{-m^2}$ bound is telling us.

Comment: Thanks! and, is it possible to use concentration to address my second comment?

Comment: I think 'almost surely positive' is too restrict. Could I expect something weaker: 'with high probability'? I came up with a possible way. Could you please check my updated post? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No. Ignoring factors of 2 (your problem seems to have been edited to include a factor of 2), the bound $e^{-m^2}$ is basically the best you can do. You cannot get a useful bound that is independent of $m$. For example, similar to the later answer, take $m=10^{-100}$ and a Gaussian PDF for $F$ that is symmetric about $m$, then $P[F\leq 0] \approx 1/2$.

Comment: But the bound I obtained from left tail bound is $P(f\leq -a)\leq \exp(-(Ef+a)^2)$ and it depends on $Ef=m$. It seems work?

Comment: If you want to compute $P[F\leq -a]$ for general $a\in \mathbb{R}$, under the assumption $-m-a\leq 0$,  that is done with the same reasoning as my answer: $$P[F\leq -a]=P[F-m\leq -m-a]\leq P[|F-m|\geq m+a]$$ Then the right-hand-side is bounded by either $e^{-(m+a)^2}$ or $2e^{-(m+a)^2}$ depending on which tail assumption you use. Your original version of the question only seemed to care about the case $a=0$.